# Simular erro de saldo insuficiente no PayPal

Tags: android, pagamento-online

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android no qual eu preciso integrar o PayPal na parte de compra, estou usando o PayPal Sandbox para testar, parecia estar funcionando perfeitamente. Crio minha conta pessoal e a conta *business* e as transações *fakes* estão funcionando, pois estou checando no site do PayPal Developer.

Ao desenvolver a parte de tratamento de erros o primeiro erro que eu pretendia tratar era a questão de fundos insuficientes... mas o problema é que mesmo a minha conta de teste pessoal estando com fundos de R$0,00 as transações *fakes* continuam a ser confirmadas e o dinheiro é repassado.

O que eu posso estar errando ou o que posso fazer para simular esses erros no Android?

Comment: Eu sou usuário de muito tempo do paypal e posso te dizer que a conta não precisa necessáriamente ter saldo. Se a conta em questão tiver um meio de pagamento registrado (Cartão de Crédito) o pagamento é debitado no cartão e o dinheiro repassado para sua conta.

Comment: Você está usando [cartões de teste](https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/)? Se sim, você pode usar gatilhos de rejeição ([rejection triggers](https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/#rejection-triggers)) para simular erros. Para simular fundos insuficientes, por exemplo, use o seguinte valor no campo "nome" quando inserir os dados do cartão: `CCREJECT-IF`.